# Lots of duplicate results when looping with condition

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to display all entries of a database in the frontend, which worked fine until I needed to get Post via a join with another table.
Now when I loop through the posts I get a lot of duplicate outputs and I cant get my head around how to accomplish the correct output.

Here is my controller code:

```
public function getApplications()
{
    $query = Bewerbungen::query();


    $bewerbungen = $query->orderBy('Bewerbung_ID')->get();

    $stellenanzeigen_name = Post::join('bewerbungens', 'posts.id', '=', 'bewerbungens.Stellenanzeigen_ID')
        ->get(['bewerbungens.Stellenanzeigen_ID' , 'posts.Titel']);

    
    $data = [
        'bewerbungen' => $bewerbungen,
        'stellen_names' => $stellenanzeigen_name,
    ];

    return view('bewerbungen_overview')->with($data);

}
```

Here is my blade code:

```
@foreach($bewerbungen as $bewerbung)
                @foreach($stellen_names as $stellen_name)
                    @if($bewerbung->Stellenanzeigen_ID === $stellen_name->Stellenanzeigen_ID)

                    <div
                    class="p-10 grid-cols-3 grid-rows-3 gap-4 shadow-2xl mb-10 bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 border-solid border-2 border-black rounded-lg">
                    <!--Card 1-->
                        <div
                            class="overflow-hidden row-span-3 bg-gray-100 shadow-2xl border-solid border-2 border-gray-500 rounded-lg">
                            <div class="pt-2 pl-6 mt-3"> {{ $stellen_name->Titel }}</div>
                            <div class="pt-4 pl-8 font-medium text-xl font-bold font-serif">
                                Kontakt: {{ $bewerbung->bewerber_email }}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
```

So pretty much I am checking if the the ID's match and if they do I want to display the data. but I get a lot of duplicate outputs.
I thought about ending the loop when the number of database entries is reached, but I don't know if that's possible /makes sense.
I am fairly new to laravel so any help appreciated :)

Edit: Here is a picture of the output when I `dd($data)`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba7pc.png

This has the right amount of entries and the correct data

Comment: I would suggest doing two steps. First, perform a simple `get()` on your result, then look into the laravel docs topic collections and there look for "unique" ;)

Comment: hey @Paladin when I dd() the $data it works fine, I only have as many attributes as my database has. So I thought It is an issue with my loops, something like I loop through it too often

Comment: Why don't you use a relation from your `Bewerbungen` to your `Post` and just call this relation? You can save a lot of code with that.
So, example, you have a table (and a model) for your `Bewerbungen` and there is a table for your `Stellenanzeigen`. You should have a `Bewerbungen.StellenanzeigeId` pointing to the `Stellenanzeige` the `Bewerbung` is for.
Then you can define in your `Bewerbungen::class` a relation `Bewerbungen::stellenanzeige` and then just call `Bewerbungen::with('stellenanzeigen')->orderBy(something);`  and you are done

Comment: @Paladin so you mean a foreign key that saves the PostID in the Bewerbung? Or is a relation something different?

Comment: It's kind of both, foreign keys is a thing to do in your database, relations are the powertools for that in laravel. See here for more details: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Oh great didn't know about that. So I don't have to rerun the migrations if I add these hasOne and hasMany relationships in the Model classes?

Comment: Assuming you already have migrations, you just run `php artisan make:migration AlterBewerbungenAddRelations` to create a new migration file, in that file, you can alter the existing database tables to fit your needs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#updating-tables